# mysql query all records with no timestamp before x date

Tags: mysql

I have table that records logins for users. I'm having trouble finding a query that will efficiently pull all unique users who have not had a login timestamp before a date of my choosing. I can easily find this information if I query per-user.

Fields are essentially:

```
 id, username, login, logout
```

I need a query that will find all `username`s that have no `logout` timestamp in 2011-11. The fact that there are multiple join events for a single easier is what's confusing me.

Comment: Start writing the query so we can have an idea on how your table look like and help you. maybe just the schema will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude all users that had at least one `logout` at the date in question with a negated semi join (EXISTS) like this:

```
SELECT u.username
FROM   users u
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM   log
   WHERE  log.username = u.username
   AND    date(logout) = '2011-11-11')
```

This will not multiply rows from `users`. If `2011-11` is supposed to signify the month of November 2011:

```
...
   AND    logout >= '2011-11-01 0:0'
   AND    logout <  '2011-12-01 0:0'
```

---

#### Additional answer to question in comments

Flag the first login of users in the log

```
ALTER TABLE log ADD COLUMN first_log boolean; -- boolean flag

UPDATE log
     ,(SELECT username, min(login) AS min_log
       FROM   log
       GROUP  BY 1) x
SET    log.first_log = TRUE
WHERE  (log.username, log.login) = (x.username, x.min_log);
```

You *can* do that, but there are many more rows in table `log` than in table `users`. I would advise instead:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN first_log datetime;

UPDATE users u
     ,(SELECT username, min(login) AS min_log; -- datetime col
       FROM   log
       GROUP  BY 1) x
SET    u.first_log = x.min_log
WHERE  u.username = x.username
```

Comment: Quick follow up - what's the easiest way for me to add a flag (to a new field, likely) to the record with the earliest timestamp for a user? So I could easily flag the first time they logged in, so I can better collect those "first joins" for other uses?

Comment: @BotskoNet: I added another answer to my answer.